# Custom email template for status

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail

I am using Custom order status While changing it send a mail. It's working fine

```
$order->sendOrderUpdateEmail(true, null);
```

How to send custom email template(New Template) per status?

```
public function shipementorderAction(){
                $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

                $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);
                $order->setData('state', 'shipement');
                $order->setStatus('shipement');
                $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('', false);
                $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
                $order->save(); 

                $order->sendOrderUpdateEmail(true, null);

                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                    $this->__('The order state has been changed.')
                );
                //$this->_redirect('mpshippingmanager/shipping/index');
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session') ->addSuccess('Order Updated Successfully'); $this->_redirectReferer();


                }
```

Comment: are you use custom email template  in function $order->sendOrderUpdateEmail(true, null); or create new custom function : $order->sendOrderCustomStatusUpdateEmail(true, null);for email template?

Comment: Check my update question i want to use custom function

Answer (score 2):

I am not clear not about your question, may be you want to *`change Order update  email`*  template **`basic of one Custom order status`**

So,you need to **rewrite class** [Mage_Sales_Model_Order](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php#L1384)  and at `queueOrderUpdateEmail()`  you need to do  customize.

In default magento,on  basic customer type ***(register/guest )*** send  different html template.[see at line 1399](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php#L1399) of that function

```
    // Retrieve corresponding email template id and customer name
    if ($this->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
        $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_UPDATE_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
        $customerName = $this->getBillingAddress()->getName();
    } else {
        $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_UPDATE_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
        $customerName = $this->getCustomerName();
    }
```

for you case,you need to set different email template of order status.

### Follow the below steps

- Create your email template and place it in template folder.For my
  case it was `app\locale\Your_Language\template\email\sales`. Suppose
  it's name is **order_update_custom_order.html** which is replicated of
  ** order_update.html**
- Create your new module. Define email template at config.xml .

  `<global>
  ...
  <template>
  <email>
  <order_update_custom_order module="sales">
   <label>custom email module</label>
   <file>sales/order_update_custom_order.html</file>
   <type>html</type>
  </order_update_custom_order>
  </email>
  </template>
  ... 
  </global>`
- then set this template basic of you custom order status at 1407 line

> `if($this->getStatus()=='Your_Custom_Order_status');
>       $templateId = 'order_update_custom_order';
>       endif;`

Comment: Can you please tell me the file path

Comment: which file location?

Comment: Config.xml and custom order status at 1407 line

Comment: create a custom module add this config.xml code. line 1407 no means https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php#L1407

Comment: ok where i have to add that if loop